# WebAPI does not instantiate objects when using Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have controller with Attribute routing similar to this.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/user")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] UserModel user)
    {
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user)  
    } 
}
```

If I send in no parameters to this controller, "user" is null.  But if I remove the attribute routing from the controller/method, the "user" object is instantiated with default values.

I read from previous posts that JSON.net will instantiate these objects by default but what I cannot find is why attribute routing removes this functionality.

Comment: @Nkosi sorry about that. It was a typo on my part.  I edited the post.

Comment: Show how the request is sent

Comment: @Nkosi  just using a browser:  http://localhost/api/v1/user

Comment: Please clarify: If you remove `Route("")` as attribute AND you send an empty Get request then the result is an instantiated instance of type `UserModel` as parameter in your method?? This seems unlikely to me...

Comment: @HeonAle, with no parameters? then how do you expect the model to be populated

Comment: @Igor yes, this is exactly what happens.  Just to clarify, this is an out of the box implementation of a web api project.  I have all the default RouteConfig and WebApiConfig